# Python Arrays automatically expand or not?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to Python and some body told me that 
"Python arrays automatically expand in size if needed."

Is it true? I couldn't find it in documentation of Python 3.3.2. Any authentic resource or guidance which answers the question. Thanks.

Comment: In Python, there are no arrays, there are "lists" and yes, they expand automatically as they are not initiated with a size limit. This question however, is not suited for this site, And you could have easily discovered the answer on your own by Googling it, asking anybody who knows anything about Python, or reading the docs.

Answer (score 4):

Depends what you mean by "automatically":

```
>>> foo = list()
>>> foo.append(1)
>>> foo
[1]
>>> foo[1] = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
>>> foo[1:] = [0]
>>> foo
[1, 0]
```

So `append` increases the length of the list to accommodate the new elements. Index assignment does not expand the array. Slice assignment does expand the array.

Comment: Slice assignment can also shrink (or remove) portions of a `list`

Answer (score 3):

That statement refers to the space allocation in memory. And yes, it's true!. You can make a list (Not array, this is python) and expand, extend, modify it anyway you like, since Python doesn't limit the size.

```
>>> l = [1, 2]
>>> l.extend([3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Here, you can see that `l` originally had two items, and then extended, it now has 6 items.

Next, you can also make it shorter:

```
>>> l.pop()
6
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This removes the last item of the list.

There are a lot of ways to modify a list, you can see the details [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm). Hope this helps!